# "BLOGDOWN_POST_RELREF">: error calling getenv: access denied: "BLOGDOWN_POST_RELREF" is not whitelisted in policy "security.funcs.getenv"

Tags: blogdown

I stopped blogging for a while, then when I came back to my blog working on a new machine with different packages versions.

Apparently my old version of tranquilpeak theme didnt work with the freshly installed version of Hugo, so I did blogdown::install_theme("kakawait/hugo-tranquilpeak-theme", force = TRUE) to fix this.

blogdown::build_site() then returned the following error:

```
Error: Error building site: "/home/simon/git/snippets/content/post/2021-10-01-quels-sont-les-monuments-les-plus-courants/index.html:14:14": failed to render shortcode "blogdown/postref": failed to process shortcode: "/home/simon/git/snippets/layouts/shortcodes/blogdown/postref.html:1:10": execute of template failed: template: shortcodes/blogdown/postref.html:1:10: executing "shortcodes/blogdown/postref.html" at <getenv "BLOGDOWN_POST_RELREF">: error calling getenv: access denied: "BLOGDOWN_POST_RELREF" is not whitelisted in policy "security.funcs.getenv"; the current security configuration is:

[security]
  enableInlineShortcodes = false
  [security.exec]
    allow = ['^dart-sass-embedded$', '^go$', '^npx$', '^postcss$']
    osEnv = ['(?i)^(PATH|PATHEXT|APPDATA|TMP|TEMP|TERM)$']

  [security.funcs]
    getenv = ['^HUGO_']

  [security.http]
    methods = ['(?i)GET|POST']
    urls = ['.*']
```

Answer (score 1):

minimal version: `blogdown::serve_site()` should fix it.

short version:  edit "layouts/shortcodes/blogdown/postref.html" in your repo to replace BLOGDOWN_POST_RELREF with HUGO_BLOGDOWN_POST_RELREF.

long version: The [changelog of blogdown:](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/blogdown/news/index.html)  lists the following bug fix from December 2021:
*Deal with the new security policy in Hugo 0.91.0 by renaming the internal environment variable BLOGDOWN_POST_RELREF (in the shortcode layouts/shortcodes/blogdown/postref.html) to HUGO_BLOGDOWN_POST_RELREF (thanks, @Nitheshnirmal #672, @gergiu #673).*

I ended up manually editing the file  "layouts/shortcodes/blogdown/postref.html"  from my repo to replace the line

```
{{ if eq (getenv "BLOGDOWN_POST_RELREF") "true" }}{{ .Page.RelPermalink }}{{ else }}{{ .Page.Permalink }}{{ end }}
```

with the line

```
{{ if eq (getenv "HUGO_BLOGDOWN_POST_RELREF") "true" }}{{ .Page.RelPermalink }}{{ else }}{{ .Page.Permalink }}{{ end }}
```

Comment: I don't recommend manually editing the file. If you must, make sure you don't leave a new line at the end. I recommend using `blogdown::serve_site()`, which will automatically update this file, unless you are using a very old version of **blogdown**.

Comment: that's good to know, thanks!  I'm ... 70%..  sure I had tried both serve_site() and build_site() before going the manually editing route.